# Input string was not in a correct format_ C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I have a field which **displays negative number**(Example -100.00)

I wrote the following code to convert string to int. However while debugging I am getting the following error : **Input string was not in a correct format.**

```
             var GetValue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtTotal")).GetAttribute("value");
            
            // convert string to int
            int TValue = int.Parse(GetValue , NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign| NumberStyles.AllowParentheses);

                
            if (TValue > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("In this method should return a negative value");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("good");
            }
```

Can anyone help me on this please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error which you are getting is self explanatory. If you look at closely you are trying to convert float number(of type string) to an integer. If you try to convert `GetValue` to `double/float`, then it will work.

Use [`.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-5.0) instead of `Parse()` to check conversion is worked or not.

```
var GetValue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtTotal")).GetAttribute("value");
if(double.TryParse(GetValue, out double total)
   Console.WriteLine("good");
else
   throw new Exception("In this method should return a negative value");
```

Comment: I've tried your code without the selenium stuff in it and it runs fine. However, when entering a space, the same error is thrown.
What happens when you ad a ```.Trim()``` to ```GetValue```?